# How to copy SQL Server MDF and LDF file when NOT an admin account

Tags: c#, sql-server, access-denied, mdf

Requirement: a C# application running under the security context of the logged in user has a task that detaches a SQL Server database, copies the `.MDF` and `.LDF` files into a ZIP archive file, and then reattaches the database.

Database is a SQL Server 2012 Express local install.

The issue run into is that despite the folder that the data resides in allowing the user account full access, the `.MDF` and `.LDF` files in this folder are not accessible to that user account and needs admin elevation to copy and move.

If the C# application runs under administration mode, this works fine. If the C# application is not running under administration mode, the copy will always fail with an Access is Denied error.

This can be further replicated straight through the UI in Windows Explorer. If in Management Studio you detach a SQL database, if you go to the folder where the data is stored and try to copy the `.MDF` or `.LDF` file and paste them somewhere, it will prompt you for admin rights first.

How does one get around this so that a user not running the application under administration mode be able to have the application copy and move these database files?

CLARIFICATION: Attach and Detach operations always work, its the copy of the `.mdf` file that is failing. There are a lot of questions about attach operations failing and that is not what this question is about.

Comment: Try setting file security permissions on the mdf file itself for that user account. I believe SQL pretty much removes file security from the data and log folders (and thus files) except very few default user accounts and the SQL Service account user. Also if you don't get a solution here try dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Jacob.  The problem here is that a user installing this application is not going to know how to go set user account permissions, the application should just do that stuff for them.  I'll check out dba.stackexchange as well.  Appreciate the input.

Comment: First detach the file then try to copy and paste the same.

Comment: Why would you do this? Create a backup and save it in a folder that both SQL Server and the user have access to.

Comment: Because the application that I inherited to maintain does this successfully by using an MDF template that they were attaching and detaching for this operation, that for whatever reason does not have its security stripped from it, and we implemented a dacpac instead that exposed this flaw as the dacpac created database DOES strip user security from the file on the mdf and ldf files.

Comment: The operation already detaches successfully.  Detach, then try to copy causes an access denied because the mdf file cannot be copied by a normal user account.  The user needs to be an admin.  If the app runs in admin mode it works fine.

Comment: See [Bad Habits : Using MDF/LDF Files as "Backups"](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/) - you should *avoid* fiddling around with `.mdf` and `.ldf` files directly and use the **proper SQL Server backup** instead